# How to use validates_uniqueness_of an id but only for some items out of a list of items with the same id. rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, validates-uniqueness-of

I have two drop down lists. One that contains items with `bmp_id` and a sublist that includes items with that `bmp_id` (in this case it is 2) that each have a unique `bmpsublist_id`. One of the options from the main dropdown list includes five sublist options with the `bmpsublist_id`'s [3, 4, 5, 6]. I want to make it so that the user can only have **ONE** of the sublist choices with `bmpsublist_id`'s [4, 5, and 6] the `bmpsublist_id` should not be unique and would be able to be added regardless of whether the others have been added. When you submit the form, the `bmp_id` and `bmpsublist_id` are added to a table called Bmp.

This is the validation I'm using in my model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :bmp_id, :message => "TODO", if: "bmpsublist_id == 4 || bmpsublist_id == 5 || bmpsublist_id == 6 || bmpsublist_id == 7"
```

The issue with this validation is that if you add option with `bmpsublist_id` 3 first, you can no longer add those with `bmpsublist_id`'s of 4, 5, and 6 which I want to still be able to add one even if a record with `bmpsublist_id`of 3 has already been added. But if you add one of the ones with `bmpsublist_id`'s of 4, 5, or 6, you can still add the one with 3 which I don't want to change.

Any ideas? Sorry if this is super confusing. I don't really know how to explain things very well.

**UPDATE:**

I figured it out, answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually just figured it out, and it seems to be working flawlessly. This is what I put into my model. I used a function for the conditional statement instead of just a string

```
  #validations      
    validates_uniqueness_of :bmp_id, :message => "TODO", if: :pad_and_pipes_exists


  def pad_and_pipes_exists
    if bmpsublist_id == 4 || bmpsublist_id == 5 || bmpsublist_id == 6 || bmpsublist_id == 7
      sublist_ids = Array.wrap([4, 5, 6, 7])
      pads_exists = false
      sublist_ids.each do |sublist_id|
        if Bmp.find_by_bmpsublist_id(sublist_ids) != nil
          pads_exists = true
        end #end if statement
      end #end each statment
    end #end first if statement
    return pads_exists
  end #end function
```